# Pandas: Sum Only Selected Values In One Column

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a dataset as following:

```
    Data   Quantity   Price  
0   P1     1          5   
1   P2     1          7
2   P3     2          3
3   P4     1          3
4   Total  5          18
```

I want to sum only P1, P2, and P3 in the above dataframe and not P4 and Total. This can be done by multiple lines of code but how to do this using pandas.DataFrame.sum. I'm currently working with this kind of dataset of thousand lines (approx.). Any leads would be appreciated.

I saw conditional sum at other links but couldn't find a solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with select columns and `sum`:

```
s = df.loc[df['Data'].isin(['P1','P2','P3']), ['Quantity','Price']].sum()
```

Or:

```
s = df.query('Data == ["P1", "P2", "P3"]')[['Quantity','Price']].sum()
```

---

```
print (s)
Quantity     4
Price       15
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Although I didn't use the exact same code you posted. But this did provide me leads to my final answer. Posting my final code as another alternative to your solution. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case, columns to be selected (like P1, P2, and P3) are larger in number than those not to be selected, then writing the above would be a multi-line task (for hundreds of columns to be selected and almost negligible number of columns that are not to be selected). The right approach would be:

Number of(columns to be selected) >> Number of(columns to be unselected)

```
s = df1.loc[~df1['Data'].isin(['Total','P4']),['Quantity','Price']].sum()
print (s)
```

Using the following code, appends a row named as 'Total' to the end of dataframe

```
df1.loc['Total_without_P4'] = pd.Series(df1.loc[~df1['Data'].isin(['Total','P4']),['Quantity','Price']].sum() , index=['Quantity','Price'])
```

Output would be:

```
                    Data   Quantity   Price  
0                   P1     1          5   
1                   P2     1          7
2                   P3     2          3
3                   P4     1          3
4                   Total  5          18
Total_without_P4           4          15
```